# Ethereum web3 sendSignedTransaction: Insufficient funds. The account ... does not have enough funds. Required 750000000000000 and got: 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am sending a signed transaction and getting errors:

> Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from
>   does not have enough funds. Required 750000000000000 and got: 0.

The thing is my account has enough funds, you can check it here `0x002D189c25958c60736aE21C966ff3131C2AC849` And if I set gasLimit: `web3.utils.toHex(20000)`, then I get another error:

> Transaction gas is too low. There is not enough gas to cover minimal
>   cost of the transaction (minimal: 21464, got: 20000). Try increasing
>   supplied gas.

Here is my `node` / `web3` code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

// connect to Infura node
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://kovan.infura.io/api_key'))

// the addresses & private key 
const addressFrom = '0x002D189c25958c60736aE21C966ff3131C2AC849';
const contractAddress = '0x36075430619b21Fff798454e2D5C81E9C18DEe81';
const privKey = '240462d...';

//ABI objects
var contractABI = new web3.eth.Contract(
    [ ...abi... ],
    contractAddress);
const contractFunction = contractABI.methods.changeBox(5);
const functionABI = contractFunction.encodeABI();

// construct the Tx data
const rawTx = {
    //gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(25000),
    to: contractAddress,
    from: addressFrom,
    data: functionABI
    };

//sign & send Tx
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, privKey)
    .then(RLPencodedTx => {
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(RLPencodedTx['rawTransaction'])
            .on('receipt', console.log);
    });
```

Does anybody know why web3 is throwing these wrong errors?

Comment: How did you derive the address from the private key? Are you certain you have the right address for that key? Side note: you shouldn't need 10 Terawei gas price to get included in a block. The most recent few transactions were included at 30 Gigawei.

Comment: I have created the account via `Parity` and also exported the account as json file, which contains `ciphertext`, which is the private key

Comment: Also, I see you're into python. There are some python tools to do similar work, for example: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created the account via Parity and also exported the account as json file, which contains `ciphertext`, which is the private key

`cipthertext` is an *encrypted* version of the private key. This [Q&A includes some deeper background](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15494/location-of-public-and-private-keys-of-ethereum-account), if you're curious.

To get your private key, you will need the keyfile, and the password used to encrypt it. Then you can use [`web3.eth.accounts.decrypt()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#decrypt) from web3.js v1 (beta) to extract the key, like so:

```
web3.eth.accounts.decrypt({
    version: 3,
    id: '04e9bcbb-96fa-497b-94d1-14df4cd20af6',
    address: '2c7536e3605d9c16a7a3d7b1898e529396a65c23',
    crypto: {
        ciphertext: 'a1c25da3ecde4e6a24f3697251dd15d6208520efc84ad97397e906e6df24d251',
        cipherparams: { iv: '2885df2b63f7ef247d753c82fa20038a' },
        cipher: 'aes-128-ctr',
        kdf: 'scrypt',
        kdfparams: {
            dklen: 32,
            salt: '4531b3c174cc3ff32a6a7a85d6761b410db674807b2d216d022318ceee50be10',
            n: 262144,
            r: 8,
            p: 1
        },
        mac: 'b8b010fff37f9ae5559a352a185e86f9b9c1d7f7a9f1bd4e82a5dd35468fc7f6'
    }
}, 'test!'); // <-- your password for the account goes in place of 'test!'
> {
    address: "0x2c7536E3605D9C16a7a3D7b1898e529396a65c23",
    privateKey: "0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

Comment: what if the private key was exported from Metamask, and is correct, but I still get the same error as the original poster? Same issue, I have sufficient ETH in my account (testing on kovan testnet using web3.js and node)

Comment: @HardikMandankaa, sorry, I eventually switched to a .NET implementation, as I am a .NET Developer. (Nethereum). Try to post your issue in the gitter channel for web3.js - https://gitter.im/ethereum/web3.js Lots of helpful and insightful developers in that community.